# AutoMapper and convert a datetime to string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, automapper

I can't get my head round the following issue. I have a feeling it is a limitation of LINQ and expression trees, but not sure how to accept the lambda body. Can I achieve this WITHOUT creating a custom converter?

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<I_NEWS, NewsModel>()                  
              .ForMember(x => x.DateCreated, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => {
                  var dt = (DateTime)src.DateCreated;
                  return dt.ToShortDateString();                      
              }));
```

I'm getting this error:
**A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<I_NEWS, NewsModel>().ForMember(x => x.DateCreated,
  opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ((DateTime)src.DateCreated).ToShortDateString()));
```

Comment: Depends, in this case since an expression is required you can't supply a "bodied" lambda

Answer (score 25):

In order to use lambda bodies, use `.ResolveUsing` instead of `.MapFrom`.

As per the [author](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/227):

> *MapFrom has some extra stuff that needs expression trees (like null
>   checking etc).*

So your statement would look like this:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<I_NEWS, NewsModel>()                  
              .ForMember(x => x.DateCreated, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => {
                  var dt = (DateTime)src.DateCreated;
                  return dt.ToShortDateString();                      
              }));
```

Comment: Note that intellisense won't recognize which ResolveUsing overload you want until you manually reference a property of your src object https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/227#issuecomment-61118211

Answer (score 0):

If Nullable is destination then:

`Mapper.CreateMap()
             .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.StartDate,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(
                        src => string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.StartDate) ? new DateTime?() : DateTime.ParseExact(src.StartDate, DATEFORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        )
                )`