# Overwrite Existing Mapping with Automapper

Tags: c#, linq, enums, automapper

I have the following entity & view model:

```
public class Report
{
    public int? Day { get; set; }

    public int? Week { get; set; }

    public int? Month { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class ReportViewModel
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

To map this I am currently using the following.

```
Mapper.Initialize(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<Report, ReportViewModel>();
        }
```

Then select using .Project.To<>

```
var models = Context.Project().To<ReportViewModel>().ToList();
```

My issue is I am passing the enum to this query that tells me whether value needs to be Month, Week, or Day.

```
public enum ReportingPeriod
{
    None = 0,
    Monthly = 1,
    Weekly = 2,
    Daily = 4
}
```

How do I set the mapping of the Value property to be dynamic based on the enum passed?

I tried overwriting the configuration before the query executed with the following, but this did not work.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Report, ReportViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(src => src.Value, dest => dest.MapFrom(r => (reportingPeriod == ReportingPeriod.Monthly) ? 
                                                                                                                r.Month.Value : reportingPeriod == ReportingPeriod.Weekly ?
                                                                                                                                            r.Week.Value : r.Day.Value));
```

Comment: Just copy all values + the enum value to the view model and let it have a display property that chooses the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Automapper version 5.2.0, your syntax should be as below. You should use ResolveUsing instead of  MapFrom and swith-case should be within curly brackets. you dont have to use any Mapper.Initialize(). I tested this code and it works for me. I hope that it helps for you also. Cheers.

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007660/automapper-and-convert-a-datetime-to-string). see the answer from Mrchief

```
   var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Report, ReportViewModel>()
            .ForMember(src => src.Value, 
                       dest => dest.ResolveUsing(r => {
                            switch(reportingPeriod)
                            {
                                case ReportingPeriod.Daily:
                                    return r.Day.Value;
                                    break;
                                case ReportingPeriod.Weekly:
                                    return r.Week.Value;
                                    break;
                                case ReportingPeriod.Monthly:
                                    return r.Month.Value;
                                    break;
                                case default:
                                    //None
                                    return null;
                                    break;
                               }
                            }));
            });

       var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value. IMO a switch statement is clearer than nested if else:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Report, ReportViewModel>()
    .ForMember(src => src.Value, 
               dest => dest.MapFrom(r => 
                    switch(reportingPeriod)
                    {
                        case ReportingPeriod.Daily:
                            return r.Day.Value;
                            break;
                        case ReportingPeriod.Weekly:
                            return r.Week.Value;
                            break;
                        case ReportingPeriod.Monthly:
                            return r.Month.Value;
                            break;
                        case default:
                            //None
                            return null;
                            break;
                    }));
```

Comment: I agree with using the switch statement instead. That is definitely better, however, when I did this, it didn't overwrite the existing map that was created in the Mapper.Initialize() method.

Comment: What is your existing map implementation?

Comment: Mapper.Initialize(c => { c.CreateMap<Report, ReportViewModel>(); }) along with all my other maps, is in a static method called in my Global.asax.cs file of the Web API.

Comment: And where are you calling CreateMap for NegativeReport and NegativeReportModel?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that was suppose to say Report & ReportViewModel. I made the edits in the question.

Comment: Are you defining `Mapper.CreateMap<Report, ReportViewModel>()` twice by any chance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80841/discussion-between-user2325333-and-rageit).

Comment: your code is not compile-able, it return error. I am not sure if that is something to do with the newest version of automapper but it wont accept usage of switch-case just like you wrote it